Problem with getting tick from ngrx effect in marble testing JEST
I have NgRx store effect like this:
 checkStatus$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(Actions.checkstatus),
      fetch({
        run: ({ method }) => {
          const timeout: Observable<number> = interval(1000 * 60 * 2);
          //rest of code
          timeout.pipe(take(1),).subscribe(() => {
            return Actions.timeout();
          });
        }
      })
    );
  });

And i try to write jest test to check if timeout action is returned
I tried to test it in jest like this:
 it('should return timeout action', () => {
      testScheduler.run(helpers => {
        const { hot, cold, expectObservable } = helpers;

        actions$.next(Actions.checkstatus({method: method});

        expectObservable(effects.checktStatus$).toBe('120s (b|)', { b:  Actions.timeout() })
      });
    });

but all i get is
 - Expected  - 20
    + Received  +  1

    - Array [
    -   Object {
    -     "frame": 120000,
    -     "notification": Object {
    -       "error": undefined,
    -       "kind": "N",
    -       "value": Object {
    -         "type": "[action] timeOut",
    -       },
    -     },
    -   },
    -   Object {
    -     "frame": 120000,
    -     "notification": Object {
    -       "error": undefined,
    -       "kind": "C",
    -       "value": undefined,
    -     },
    -   },
    - ]
    + Array []

Am i doing something wrong? What is the problem here?

Your stream does not emit timeout action. Your return Actions.timeout() returns to the void (because subscribe doesn't use your value anyway).
Instead, you should return Actions.timeout() to the stream like this:
checkStatus$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(Actions.checkstatus),
        fetch({
            run: ({ method }) => {
                const timeout = 1000 * 60 * 2;
                //rest of code
                return of(Actions.timeout()).pipe(delay(timeout));
            }
        })
    );
});

Also, you can write a code like this to create a race between your fetch and timeout observables:
checkStatus$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(Actions.checkstatus),
        fetch({
            run: ({ method }) => {
                const timeout = 1000 * 60 * 2;
                // const fetch$ = here you create your network observable
                const timeout$ =   of(Actions.timeout()).pipe(delay(timeout));
                return fetch$.pipe(
                    raceWith(timeout$),
                );
            }
        })
    );
});

Also, you can create custom operator for this:

const timeoutFor = (timeoutAmount) => (source) => {
    const timeout$ = of(undefined).pipe(
        delay(timeout),
        switchMap(() => throwError(new Error()))
    );
    return source.pipe(
        raceWith(timeout$),
    );
}

and then use it like this:
checkStatus$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(Actions.checkstatus),
        fetch({
            run: ({ method }) => {
                const timeout = 1000 * 60 * 2;
                // const fetch$ = here you create your network observable
                return fetch$.pipe(
                    // be sure to catch timeout error like this. 
                    // Otherwise, you could catch error from your fetch$ observable 
                    timeoutFor(timeout).pipe(catchError(() => of(Actions.timeout()))),
                );
            },
        }),
    );
});

